# JQuery AJAX trying to parse XML even with "dataType" : "JSON"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

As the title suggests, I have the following:

```
$.ajax({
  "url" : ...
, "type" : "GET"
, "dataType" : "JSON"
, "success" : function(response_data) {
    that.data = response_data;
    success(response_data);
  }
, "onerror" : function(data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  }
});
```

But when I run it, I get

```
XML Parsing Error: syntax error Location: moz-nullprincipal
```

Looking at firebug, I see that the request was

```
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control   max-age=0
Connection  keep-alive
Host    localhost:8888
Referer http://localhost:8888/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101       Firefox/13.0.1
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably not the cause, but shouldn't 'json' be lower-case? And what precisely is throwing that error?

Comment: interesting, let me try lower-case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok great thanks to everyone tried to answer this.

But it turns out, as usual, I noob'ed out here.

The XML parsing error shown in firebug is not actually an error with the code, and firebug's failed attempt to guess it's XML and parse it.

My problem was elsewhere in the program and it was solved.

Upper vs lower case "JSON" did not make a difference.

Max

Comment: I has a similar issue, my ajax call did not specify the dataType of the response. Setting dataType: "text" in the call made the apparent error in the firefox dev tool go away.

Answer (score 3):

Change "JSON" to lowercase "json" first. But this is the type that jQuery is expecting back from the server, it's not necessarily what the server will send.

Are you *sure* that the server is returning JSON? Worth a double-check. Have you looked at the response in Fiddler? If it's XML it's the server's issue, not the script's.

Comment: Hm, strange. Maybe it's the JSON>json thing. If the dataType option is not set or unrecognized jQuery tries to guess the response type. If it's guessing XML incorrectly it might explain the issue. The other thing it could be is the JSON response itself is badly formed.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is that your server is not setting the 'Content-type' header.  Set it to 'application/json'.

For example in node.js:

```
res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
```